# why im get this error Fragment not attached to activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[this is my code fragmentproduct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr1Rx.png)

```
class FragmentProduct : Fragment() {

var list = ArrayList<Category>()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false)
    getCategory()
    return view
}

private fun getCategory(){
    var queue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireContext())
    var request = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.1.10/login/apicategory.php", null, Response.Listener{ response->

        for (s in 0..response.length() - 1){
            var job = response.getJSONObject(s)
            var id = job.getInt("id")
            var name = job.getString("name")
            var photo = job.getString("photo").replace("localhost", "192.168.1.10")

            list.add(Category(id, name, photo))
            var adapterku = CategoryProduct(requireContext(), list)
            recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            recycler.adapter = adapterku
        }

    }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
        Log.d("categoryEr", error.toString())
    })
    queue.add(request)
}
```

}

I get an error in the product fragment and every time I click on the product it immediately closes the app, and there is no error in the code

Comment: Instead of doing your work inside `onCreateView` do it inside `onViewCreated`.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment isn't attached to context when `onCreateView` gets called. You should call `getCategory` in `onCreate` instead. See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)).